# How to use alternation in character class

Tags: regex

Without being specific to a particular programming language I've been looking at regular expressions.

As I understand it an alternative notation to `a|b` is using a character class `[ab]`.

So if I have this regex `ab|cd` which reads as **a followed by b OR c followed by d** how can I use a character class for this?

This I assume wouldn't work: `[abcd]` so is this the right answer: `[(ab)(cd)]` - it just looks a bit strange to me for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character class alone would match only a single character. Here you need to use capturing or non-capturing group if you want to apply **OR** for group of characters.

```
(ab|cd)
```

or

```
(?:ab|cd)
```

Comment: isn't the first the same as the one in my question?

Comment: no,, `fooab|cd` and `foo(ab|cd)` are totally different.

Comment: but there wasn't anything before the `ab` in my example.

Comment: You can't put `ab|cd` inside a char class, if you do that `[ab|cd]`, this would match `a` or `b` or `|` or `c` or `d`